# Creating a subscribed plan for paid memberships on Webflow with Memberstack and Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments, webflow

Creating a subscribed plan for paid memberships on Webflow with Memberstack and Stripe

hello, was trying to set up a paid membership on my webflow site using memberstack to handle membership, stripe for payment and zappier to integrate. I was able to create the free plan, but the paid plan (the subscribed plan) of the membership is not working